# Do we know what happens at the boundary of the universe, what are some theories about it?

Tags: universe, theories

Do we know what happens at the boundary of the universe, what are some theories about it? Does space time differ at the boundary? Do things become larger at the boundary? Do the trajectories curve and force you to remain at the edge instead of crossing it? What are some theories about the edge of the universe?

Comment: The universe doesn't have an edge. However, there are several [cosmological horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_horizon).

Comment: Related: [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/32426)

Comment: I read the linked answer and it sucks. Can I take a whack at a better one here?

Comment: Go ahead. I also laughed, because the answers on that question were really bad and doesn't really answer this one.